# xcom_pull from the GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor

Tags: airflow

I want the file name from the GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor Operator. Tried using context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='check_file_gcs') where the main check_file_gcs is

```
check_file_gcs = GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor(
        task_id='check_file_gcs',  
        bucket=source_bucket,
        prefix="<file_name>",
        poke='10',
        dag=dag)
```

I am not able to get the file name from the xcom_pull. Not much experienced in Airflow. Can someone help please? How do we know the paramneters and values passed by the completion of GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor` is deprecated and doesn't have the functionality of pushing matching objects to xcom.
You should use the new sensor [GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e3bcaa3ba351234effe52ad380345c4e39003fcb/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/gcs.py#L175:L177).

Since you are using the deprecated version it means you are using `Airflow < 2.0.0` thus you will need to install [google backport provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

Then you can import the sensor with:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.gcs import GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor
```

To verify that the matching objects are pushed to xcom you can click on the `GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor` in the UI and choose Xcom tab. The list of objects will appear there.

Comment: Many thanks Elad. What is the UI link for GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor where I can see the xcom tab please?

Comment: When the task is completed, click on it -> Task Instance Details -> Xcom. There is also a direct link `https://your_airflow_instance/xcom?dag_id=your_dag_id&task_id=your_task_id&execution_date=your_execution_date`